# How to rebase backwards, preferably without using diff/apply?

Tags: git, rebase

I have the following commit history:

```
(master)              (topic)   (quickfix)
       a -> b -> c ->       d ->         e
```

I want to modify it so that it looks like so:

```
     (master, quickfix)              (topic)   
a ->                  e -> b -> c ->       d
```

In other words, `master` was at a commit `a`. I started working on a `topic` branch, but while on that branch I saw an issue and made a fix to unrelated code. I did this in a `quickfix` branch, but the branch was from `topic` instead of `master`. I'd like to merge `quickfix` back into `master`, but *without* any of the changes that were made in `topic`.

I know I can use diff/apply to ultimately get where I want to go, but this has happened to me a few times and I find the diff/apply workflow a little cumbersome. Is there a feature in git that makes this easier?

Answer (score 5):

There isn't one command to do this, but a relatively simple sequence can do it, run while working on the `master` branch:

```
# make it so that it's as if quickfix were branched off of master instead
# of topic
git rebase --onto master topic quickfix

# proceed as normal
git merge quickfix
git rebase master topic
```

The reason I didn't understand this at first was that I wasn't aware of the `--onto` option for `git rebase`.  I found out about it while reading `git help rebase`, which had a similar enough example.